# Identify every unique partition made by axis-parallel (equally-sized) squares

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we are given $n$ axis-parallel squares, which are equally sized.
I want to find the maximum number of *unique* partitions made by them.

For instance, if $n=2$, there can be at most 3 partitions. 
Also, there may be up to 7 and 13 partitions if $n$ is 3 and 4, respectively (Please see [$n=3$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oR2S.png), and [$n=4$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H72vI.png)).

So, my question is, how many partitions can I get given $n$ axis-parallel squares? (My first guess on this is $O(2^n)$ partitions, but I think it would be smaller than that number.)

I am also wondering if there's a good (hopefully, polynomial-time) algorithm to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can bound number of these partitions by the number of partitions of a big rectangle with two sets of $2n$ parallel lines. If each line is parallel to one side of bounding rectangle then each part is a rectangle. So we have $2n + 1$ parts of each line being sides of these small rectangles. So the number of internal small rectangle is $\frac{2 \cdot 4n (2n - 1)}{4} = 2n(2n - 1)$.

So replacing each square by $4$ lines containing its sides we can increase number of part and can't decrease it. Thus number of part is at most $2n(2n - 1)$.

Anyway it is possible to construct an example of $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ parts, so maximum number is some function from $\Theta(n^2)$. I guess it is $n^2 - n + 1$ and I'll try to prove this later.